# java Pair and ArrayList question

Tags: java

I already asked this question and I got additional question about using 
class I made myself.
see code below.

```
  import java.util.*;

    class Pair{
      int toWhere;
      int weight;
    }

    public class Test{
      public static void main(String[] args){
        ArrayList[] arr = new ArrayList[2];
        Pair p = new Pair();

        for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
          arr[i] = new ArrayList<Pair>();

        p.toWhere = 1;
        p.weight = 2;
        arr[0].add(p);
        System.out.println(p); // gives me Pair@525483cd
        System.out.println(arr[0].get(0)); // gives me exactly the same, Pair@525483cd
        System.out.println(p.toWhere); // gives me no error, and is 1
        System.out.println(arr[0].get(0).toWhere); // gives me an error
      } 
    }
```

my question is this.
values of p and `arr[0].get(0)` (which is address? I guess) is the same.
but why does `p.toWhere` give me the accurate value and 
`arr[0].get(0).toWhere` does not?

Comment: May be you should use this instead `ArrayList<Pair>[]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the compiler doesn't know that `arr` is an array of `ArrayList` of `Pair`. You need to type arr:

```
List<Pair>[] arr = new ArrayList[2];
```

Now when you use `arr[0].get(0)`, the compiler knows that `get` returns a `Pair` (not an `Object` as in your code), so `Pair`'s methods are available.